# sDNA: tolerance problem

Tags: sdna

I used "Prepare Network" function before conducting "Integral Analysis". However, the analysis still failed because of the tolerance problem. What's wrong?

[image]

The error message:

```
sDNA processing

sDNA is running in 64-bit mode

Building network and checking for tolerance errors...

ERROR: Edges closer than Arc's XYTolerance/Cluster Tolerance detected
these are not necessarily viewable in ArcMap
and will lead to incorrect results

Please inspect and fix using sDNA Prepare

TIME 0.0 for start_gs=;end_gs=;metric=ANGULAR;custommetric=;disable=;intermediates=;oneway=;;origweight=;destweight=;weight_type=Link;radii=400;radmetric=EUCLIDEAN;;nojunctions;nohull;bidir;arcxytol=0
.001000;arcztol=0.001000;

Calculation failed.

External command completed

Process did not complete successfully

Failed to execute (sDNAIntegral).
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run sDNA prepare again and ask it to detect (not repair) endpoint near misses on your input data - does it find any?

Is the data projected to a coordinate system that uses *metres* as the spatial unit - your config shows a tolerance of 0.001 which would make sense if so, though if you were using degrees you would likely trigger this warning as many links will be smaller than 0.001°.

If desired, it's possible to override the tolerance check by setting `xytol=0;ztol=0` in advanced config - but I would really not recommend this - find out why it is triggering first.